# Wrapping input and label field with an li

Tags: jquery

I am dynamically creating a label and input inside a ul. I need to wrap the label and input inside an li. I've tried wrap, append, appenTo, and before. I can't figure it out. Here is the code.

```
const departments = $('#departments ul');

for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                let num = response[i][0];
                let description = response[i][1];


                $('<input />', {type: 'checkbox', id: +num, value: description}).appendTo(departments);
                $('<label />', {'for': +num, text: description}).appendTo(departments);

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you need to create the new `li` element, append that to the `ul`, then append the new `input` and `label` to the `li`. Try this:

```js
const $departments = $('#departments ul');
const len = 5;

for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  let num = i; // response[i][0]; // for testing only
  let description = 'Label ' + i; // response[i][1]; // for testing only

  var $li = $('<li />').appendTo($departments);
  $('<input />', {
    type: 'checkbox',
    id: +num,
    value: description
  }).appendTo($li);
  $('<label />', {
    for: +num,
    text: description
  }).appendTo($li);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="departments">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I've never seen this jquery convention $('<input />', {type: 'checkbox', id: +num, value: description}).appendTo(departments); is it a one off?

Comment: In any cause you can use that syntax to create an element (defined in the first argument) and provide an object containing the attributes and properties to set on it (in the second argument). The documentation for that is here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes